# OverflowBox RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#7796e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT

Tags: flutter, widget

I use OverflowBox, but i get this issue.

> The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was
> fired: RenderConstrainedOverflowBox#8530c   NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:   needs compositing   creator:
> OverflowBox ← _BodyBuilder ← MediaQuery ←
> LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ←
> CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ←
> _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#f1374 ink renderer] ← NotificationListener ←
> PhysicalModel ← AnimatedPhysicalModel ← ⋯   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=331.2, 0.0<=h<=164.8)   size:
> Size(331.2, 164.8)   alignment: Alignment.center   textDirection: ltr
> minWidth: Infinity   maxWidth: use parent maxWidth constraint
> minHeight: 200.0   maxHeight: 200.0 This RenderObject had the
> following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
> child: RenderRepaintBoundary#7796e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> child: RenderCustomPaint#57723 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> child: RenderRepaintBoundary#6b624 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> child: _RenderScrollSemantics#80ff2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> child: RenderPointerListener#c1da5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderRepaintBoundary#7796e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT

The Code Is:

```
 Scaffold(
      body: OverflowBox(
        minWidth: double.infinity,
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 5,
          padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(top: 2.h),
          childAspectRatio: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 3.w,
          mainAxisSpacing: 3.w,
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: List.generate(
            5,
            (index) => Material(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                // side: ,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              color: whiteColor,
              elevation: 5,
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
              shadowColor: shadowColor.withOpacity(0.5),
              child: Text(
                "Skill${index + 1}",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                // textDirection: TextDirection.,

                // textDirection: TextD,

                style: Get.textTheme.headline3!.copyWith(
                  color: faddenGreyColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you. I think this problem is `minWidth: double.infinity,` remove this and add `shrinkWrap: true,` to the inside `GridView`

Refer GridView [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html)

Create Grid list [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/grid-lists)

Refer shrinkWrap proprty [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html)

```
 OverflowBox(
      child: GridView.count(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),// if you add extra index(like 10,50,etc) then used physics
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(top: 2),
      childAspectRatio: 2,
      crossAxisSpacing: 3,
      mainAxisSpacing: 3,
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      children: List.generate(
        5,
        (index) => Material(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            // side: ,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          elevation: 5,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
          child: Center(
               child: Text(
               "Skill${index + 1}",
               textAlign: TextAlign.center,
             ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer Below Code:

```
Scaffold(
        body: OverflowBox(
     // minWidth: double.infinity,
      child:  GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 5,
          padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(top: 2.h),
          childAspectRatio: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 3.w,
          mainAxisSpacing: 3.w,
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: List.generate(
          5,
          (index) => Material(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              // side: ,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            color:whiteColor,
            elevation: 5,
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
          shadowColor: shadowColor.withOpacity(0.5),
            child: Text(
              "Skill${index + 1}",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              // textDirection: TextDirection.,

              // textDirection: TextD,

              style: Get.textTheme.headline3!.copyWith(
                color: faddenGreyColor,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ),
      )
    ))
```

Comment: i need to know why `OverflowBox` has an issue @Darshini R Gowda

Comment: OverflowBox not an issue. Don't give  minWidth: double.infinity, you comment  this line its working fine.